# How Can I Input A Custom Class Value Via Scanner?

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am trying to put together a small test application that takes inputs via scanner and puts them in-memory via hashmap and tree set.

Later on I'll search, edit, and delete them (So basically a CRUD), it requires 2 classes an employee class and a company one. I'm trying to take the input for the employee with all the information for the employee including the company which is a foreign custom class object in the POJO.

It won't let me class cast it, what should I do?

Here is the POJO

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String ssn;
    private Integer salary;
    private String birthDate;
    private String jobTitle;
    @ManyToOne
    private Company companyName;

   public Employee (String fN, String lN, String SSN, Integer sal, String birth, String jobT, Company compName) {       
    lastName = lN;
    firstName = fN;
    SSN = ssn;
    sal = salary;
    birth = birthDate;
    jobT = jobTitle;
    compName = companyName;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Employee[Last Name= " + lastName + ", First Name= " + firstName + " SSN= " + ssn + ","
            + "Salary= " + salary + ", Birth Date= " + birthDate + ", Job Title= " + jobTitle + ",]" ;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getSsn() {
    return ssn;
}

public void setSsn(String ssn) {
    this.ssn = ssn;
}

public Integer getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

public String getJobTitle() {
    return jobTitle;
}

public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
}

public Company getCompanyName() {
      return companyName;
 }

public void setCompanyName(Company companyName) {
       this.companyName = companyName;
}
}
```

Here is part of the class the scanner is in

```
        System.out.println("Enter Company Name : ");
          String val7 = input1.nextLine();
          ...             
          Employee newEmp = new Employee(str1,str2, str3,    val4, str5, str6, val7);
```

If I pass the str7 in, it obviously creates an error as the method takes the CompanyName.

Any idea what I need to be doing as ClassCast doesn't work here.

EDIT here is the company class
    public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    String companyName;
    private String description;

```
public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}
public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

Comment: Add the complete stactrace and a [mcve]

Comment: _If I pass the str7 in_. there is nothing called `str7` within your code. Though the seventh parameter of the `Employee` constructor should take a type `Company`.

Comment: You have to first create your Company (via a Company constructor of your choice) and then pass that Company into the constructor of Employee!

Comment: it's not clear what the problem is, but you have a logical error in the constructor, this `compName = companyName;` should be the other way around ... like this `companyName = compName ;` cuz u want to assign the value from param to the member, not vice versa

Comment: There is no stack trace yet, it's not able to be run untiil I get past this part.

Comment: I added the company class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create instance of Company, don't pass it as string:

```
System.out.println("Enter Company Name : ");
String val7 = input1.nextLine();
Company company = new Company();
company.setCompanyName(val7);
```

and use `company` instead of `val7` when you create `Employee`

```
Employee newEmp = new Employee(str1,str2, str3,    val4, str5, str6, company);
```

**ALSO** you have a logical error in the constructor, this

```
compName = companyName;
```

should be the other way around ... like this

```
companyName = compName;
```

because you want to assign the value from param to the member,

Answer (score 0):

There is only the way you already half took:

- you use the scanner and ask for the values that you need to create a new instance of that class
- you validate all those values
- you use them to create the object

Like:

```
while (something) {
  String newFirstName = scanner.next();
  ...
  int newSalary = scanner.nextInt();
  ...
  Employee newGuy = new Employee(newFirstName, ...
```

In other words: Scanner only knows how to provide those specific "built-in" types such as String, int, float, ...

Thus: if you need an aggregate of such types, you have collect them "manually".

In your case: simply ask for **companies** first. Meaning: have the user first enter the companies; and your code create company objects. You could put those into a `Map<String, Company>` for example. Now, when entering employees, you ask for the company name last; and then your code retrieves the Company object for the name entered.

Comment: So collect them without the scanner, but put them in the object?

Comment: See my updates. The point is: a scanner cant return a Company object to you. Only strings, numbers, ... so you need to work around that.